# custom filters array for field type select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

i need filter one Which receives an array of integers.

```
<select class="form-control"
                            ng-model="vm.data.form.idService"
                            ng-options="service.idService as
                            service.title for service in vm.data.services 
                            |  filter: {active: 'true'} 
                            |  inArray:vm.data.form.servicesIds:'idService'"></select>
```

my custom filter is:

```
angular.module('mainApp').filter('inArray', function($filter){
    return function(list, arrayFilter, element){
        if(arrayFilter){
            return $filter("filter")(list, function (listItem) {
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayFilter.length; i++) {
                    debugger;
                    if (arrayFilter[i][element] == listItem[element]){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
    };
```

The var vm.data.form.servicesIds the result is: {{11,12}}, but is not working.

The purpose of this filter is to receive an array and filter as in T-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM SERVICES WHERE IdService in (11,12)
```

a erro is this:

```
angular.js:13550 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: inArrayFilterProvider <- inArrayFilter
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=inArrayFilterProvider%20%3C-NaNnArrayFilter
    at http://localhost/Gvisa.Web/assets/lib/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost/Gvisa.Web/assets/lib/angular.js:4458:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost/Gvisa.Web/assets/lib/angular.js:4611:39)
    at http://localhost/Gvisa.Web/assets/lib/angular.js:4463:45
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost/Gvisa.Web/assets/lib/angular.js:4611:39)
    at http://localhost/Gvisa.Web/assets/lib/angular.js:19531:24
    at isStateless (http://localhost/Gvisa.Web/assets/lib/angular.js:14236:12)
    at findConstantAndWatchExpressions (http://localhost/Gvisa.Web/assets/lib/angular.js:14293:33)
    at http://localhost/Gvisa.Web/assets/lib/angular.js:14247:7
    at forEach (http://localhost/Gvisa.Web/assets/lib/angular.js:322:20)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:13550
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this valid syntax: " )( "  ?

Comment: @Julo0sS no is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you injecting $filter over here

```
angular.module('mainApp').filter('inArray', function($filter){
```

it's not required.
just keep it like

```
angular.module('mainApp').filter('inArray', function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a parenthesis in the last line of your filter

```
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was comparing an object with a simple array.

And solved the semicolon

```
angular.module('mainApp').filter('inArray', function($filter){
    return function(list, arrayFilter, element){
        if(arrayFilter){
            return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem){
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayFilter.length; i++) {
                    debugger;
                    if (arrayFilter[i] == listItem[element])
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Thank you very much